# Speeding up app using many threads

Tags: android, multithreading, image, get

im currently working on a android app that has to GET over 70 images all from different urls. I am currently using the asynctask to GET all the images. would my app load the images faster if i was to create many threads and divide task of getting 70 images between the threads like 20 on one thread and 50 on another?

Comment: Are they the same 70 images each time, or different each time, or sometimes the same, sometimes different?

Comment: guys from Volley at Google found out by testing that apparently 4 threads is good. (their library is quite fast, as a matter of fact).

Comment: they can be the same or different

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to load all 70 images at the same time? It might depend on the speed of the internet connection but basically I guess the time to completely load all images would be the same, whether you load them sequentially or in parallel. Sequentially, each image can be loaded using the full internet bandwidth, while loading the images in parallel could only use a fraction of the bandwidth, so in the end the total amount of time will be roughly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can imagine that having multiple http connections each managed by different thread may be beneficial for the performance. 
 The best way to determine the number of threads to use (could be > 2) is to benchmark your piece of code for overall download time (i.e. between begin until all images have been loaded).
For downloading multiple images asynchronously I would also recommend using [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library.

Answer (score 0):

It has very few chances to get faster, because time of loading is due to time of the connection.

The right way to do I think, is to think about designing your application better, to avoid retrieving 70 images in one time, because I don't know your application, but do you really need to display 70 images in same time ? It would be better to load images only when you want to display it. This for 2 main reasons :

1. Your activity will be displayed faster
2. Your user may not have an unlimited data plan and is maybe not on wi-fi

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently using the asynctask to GET all the images. would my app
>   load the images faster if i was to create many threads and divide task
>   of getting 70 images between the threads like 20 on one thread and 50
>   on another?

If you are using a single task to download all your (70) images that is not a proper way for it. Of course you should use separate tasks while downloading images if you want them to be downloaded faster.(I assume there is no constraint for downloading images sequentially) If you continue using a single task to download 70 images, they are going to be downloaded one by one and it will take long.

Use a library for image downloading. It is a painful job to load remote images. I suggest you to use a library for this. I'm currently using [ShutterBug](https://github.com/applidium/Shutterbug). Try it.